# how to get the fan page name of Facebook wall post?

Tags: user-interface, facebook-c#-sdk

I am reading the wall posts of fan pages under my FB account using C# SDK. I would like to know the page id of the wall post. Is there any property in C# SDK?

Comment: how did you get to the posts without having the page id?

Answer (score 0):

As people start to use the Graph objects more an more, the FQL seems to be fading.  But FQL is not deprecated (at least not yet).

For a particular wall post you're reading via your C# SDK, simply FQL it:

`SELECT source_id FROM stream WHERE post_id = {post_id}`

For more information https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

For information on how to make an FQL query run in the C# SDK, see: 
http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Making-Requests.aspx

But it's going to look something like this

```
var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
// this is where you already grab your post, so you have post_id
var data = client.query("SELECT source_id FROM stream WHERE post_id =" + post_id);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your message. I am actually looking for Page_Id or Page name where the message is posted on?

Comment: `/me/accounts` will give you a complete list of apps and pages you have under your account.